# What is the best way to parse large text file (>5 GB) in python to address memory issue?

Tags: python

I had tried the below two ways.

1. First way

```
    with open("largefile.txt","r") as f:
       f1 = f.readlines()
       for x in f1:
          some processing
```

2. Second way

```
    for x in open("largefile.txt","r"):
        some processing
```

Also, how can I check the memory usage precisely

Comment: How to check memory usage depends on your OS. Number 2 generally is better for memory usage.

Comment: Third way - use `with` context manager to open the file (like 1), then iterate over file handler `f`, no `readlines()`

Comment: What's wrong with the second way? What does your processing do?

Comment: The important things are not to read the whole file into memory (your second way looks better here), and not to build up some data structure while processing that grows linearly (or worse) with the size of the file. Beyond that there is not enough detail in the question to answer it more specifically.